Direction of dipole after spontaneous emission
Consider a simple $J'= 1$ to $J = 0$ transition for an atom. If the magnetic field set the quantization along the z-direction, I am wondering what is the direction of the dipole moment after the atom decays from different $m_J$, where $m_J$ is the projection of angular momentum to the z-axis, states to the ground state.
From my understanding, $\pi$ transition ($\Delta m_J = 0$) will align the dipole moment to the z-axis $e_z$, and $\sigma$ transitions ($\Delta m_J = \pm$) will align the dipole moment to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x\pm iy)$. But I cannot confirm if this concept is correct.
